# Using element locators in Cucumber tables

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, gherkin

I have a login Test where I run both positive and negative scenarios using tables in cucumber.

Scenario Outline: Login

```
Given User navigates to Field
And User enters a "<Username>" username
And User enters a "<Password>" password
When User clicks on the login button
Then User should see the "<message>"

Examples:
  | Username | Password  | message |
  | name  | pwd | Logout |
  | name1 | pwd1 | Your login name or password is incorrect.|
```

I now assert it using the "message".

My question is : Is it possible to assert using xpath or other element locators? Is this a recommend way or should I create different scenario for every case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not combine valid or invalid cases in one scenario. In almost all cases, there will be a different page flow. You will need to handle it with if conditions to take this into account. Keep them separate and avoid complexities.

Another advantage of keeping them separate is if you want to run only the valid cases. Just put a tag on that scenario and mention it in the runner.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to assert using xpath or other element locators?

Yes it is possible.

You can assert it like this :

```
String successMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("some xpath")).getText();
```

and you already have expected msg (meaning you already know what should be expected).

```
String expected = "your expected msg";
```

Now all you have to do is compare these two strings.

In **testng** something like :

`Assert.assertEquals(successMsg, expected)` would do the job.

Reference :

[Cucumber assertion](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/checking-assertions/#java)